# How to bubble up an event to the very top parent React style?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a set of components `app->page->list_container->list->item`
My goal is to notify the `app` that click happened on `item` level.
If there is simple relation like `parent->child` I could use props and do something like: `<Child onClick={this._onClick}> ...` and then use `this.props.onClick()` to make a callback.
But what is the best native React-style receipt for doing the same trick with a tree of components? How to notify the `app`, that `item` was clicked without calling to Flux/Reflux, Elm and other supported libs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Standard react way:**
Passing `onClick` function as a prop down your component tree is the standard react-way of doing this.

In `<app>`:

```
<page onClick={this._onClick}>
```

In `<page>`:

```
<list_container onClick={this.props.onClick}>
```

Etcetera.

Or you could use:

```
<list_container {...this.props}>
```

To automatically pass down any prop from parent component to the child component.

In a deep tree, this can and will get quite tedious/ lot of work. React was not designed for this purpose.
React is made for (top-down) smart and fast component-tree rendering.
The frameworks for the flux pattern you mention are designed to handle the other interactive functions.

***Alternative shortcut (not recommended):***
A shortcut you could possibly use is to add a listener directly on the DOM, inside your `<app>` component, that handles the click event on the item:

In `<app>` component, add:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var itemElementInDOM = document.getElementById('myItem');
  itemElementInDOM.addEventListener('click',this._onClick);
}
```

And in your `<item>` component, give the item a (unique) id.

I would generally NOT recommend this:

- In a typical react tree setup, the lower level components (like
  `<item>`) may be rendered more than once, and then you would need
  additional logic to ensure that each ID is unique.
- You would also
  need to add some additional smarts to make sure you remove the listener if the
  item(s) in question are removed from the DOM.

Comment: Thanks. But somehow I was sure that bubbling up an event or state to root component  is a common task. And it is really strange for me that it has such a tedious solution. Maybe something wrong with the way I'm constructed my code? Is any common React way to do it right?

Comment: Common react-only way is bubbling up. But React does not like bubbling up (also called antipattern). Mixing parent to child communication with child to parent communication makes code harder to debug. That is why flux - with one-way data flow - often goes hand in hand with react.